# Erro ao tentar alterar ícone de aplicação JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, icons

Olá. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em JavaFX e estou tentando alterar o ícone da minha aplicação, conforme o código abaixo:

```
public class Login extends Application 

{

Image applicationIcon = new Image("/src/Icons/message.png");

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) 

{

try 

    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../FXML/Login.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Login");

        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Login.class.getResourceAsStream("src/Icons/message.png")));           
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(applicationIcon);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


    } 

catch (IOException e) 

    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

No entanto, ao executar o script para alteração do ícone da aplicação, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Exception in Application constructor
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance:
>   class application.Login   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$165(LauncherImpl.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
>   URL: Invalid URL or resource not found    at
>   javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)     at
>   javafx.scene.image.Image.(Image.java:620)   at
>   application.Login.(Login.java:24)   ... 13 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
>     at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)    ... 15 more
>   Exception running application application.Login

Os arquivos do programa que estou a desenvolver, estão dispostos da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe porque ocorre esse erro?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Já faz um tempo que eu não uso JavaFX, mas pelo que eu estou vendo o problema esta no caminho da imagem, "src/Icons/message.png"

Ele esta procurando a pasta src/Icons a partir do caminho relativo da classe
tente usar de maneira semelhante ao arquivo FXML como "../Icons/message.png"

Comment: Consegui. Fiz a alteração do código para o seguinte:
public static final String ICON_IMAGE_LOC = "/icons/message.png";
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new javafx.scene.image.Image(ICON_IMAGE_LOC));